# In Flutter, how do I make Positioned items in a Stack scroll with the background grid?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a sort of weekly schedule with Flutter and want to make a background grid showing times/sized boxes and then layer items on top that will span between those boxes. Currently, I'm trying to create a List View of cells (which scrolls fine horizontally, I just haven't added a vertical scrolling list yet) but when I add positioned items to the Stack, they stay in place instead of scrolling with the page. How can I make these items scroll? And should I be using this strategy for this anyway?

Here's my code so far:

```
   return Expanded(
     child: Stack(
       children: [
         ListView(scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, children: [
           ...days
               .map((stage) => Container(
                     width: 100,
                     child: Column(
                       children: [
                         Text(day),
                         ...times.map((time) => Container(height: 100, child: Text(time))),
                       ],
                     ),
                   ))
               .toList(),
         ]),
         Container(
           child: Positioned(
             top: 20,
             bottom: 20,
             left: 100,
             right: 200,
             child: Container(
               height: 100,
               width: 100,
               child: Text('waddup'),
               color: Colors.blue,
             ),
           ),
         ),
       ],
     ),
   );
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share an image of your desired layout and behavior? Also, have you thought about a [grid](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/grid-lists)?

Comment: @tomerpacific just added an image of what it looks like. Currently scrolling keeps that blue and black box in the same spot on the page (doesn't scroll with the background). But ideally I would like them to stay in that column with the day as it scrolls. I tried using a grid but ran into the same issue so am trying this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void fileMain() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(
        event: event,
      ),
    ),
  );
}

final now = DateTime.now();
final tomorrow = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day + 1);
final days = List.generate(7, (index) {
  final day = now.add(Duration(days: index));
  return '${day.day}/${day.month}?${day.year}';
});

final times = List.generate(24,
    (h) => '${(h % 12).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:00 ${h < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM'}');

final event = Event(
  start: tomorrow.add(const Duration(hours: 10)),
  duration: const Duration(hours: 2),
  title: 'My Event',
);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({
    super.key,
    required this.event,
  });

  final Event event;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final eventTop = event.start.hour * 50.0;
    final eventHeight = event.duration.inHours * 50.0;

    final dayDifferent = event.start.difference(now).inDays;

    final eventLeft = dayDifferent * 100.0 + 100;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        ...days
                            .map((day) => Container(
                                  width: 100,
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Text(day),
                                      ...times.map(
                                        (time) => Container(
                                          height: 50,
                                          child: Text(time),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ))
                            .toList(),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      top: eventTop,
                      left: eventLeft,
                      child: IgnorePointer(
                        child: Container(
                          height: eventHeight,
                          width: 100,
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Text(event.title),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Event {
  final DateTime start;
  final Duration duration;
  final String title;

  const Event({
    required this.start,
    required this.duration,
    required this.title,
  });
}
```

Comment: This is how it's working now and what I don't want. I want the blue box to move with the times. For example, if it's an event from 10:30am to 11:30am, it should stay in that location among the times.

Comment: I see this is edited and looks like it works for my case, thank you!